# get document from multi collection for each user firebase swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Im trying to get document from firestore collection for each user , for example let say if user logged in with  this email "Hola@example.com" ,  i want to get document from collection named "Hola" , and if user logged in with this email "Hi@example.com" i want to get document from "Hi" collection i tried this code but it didn't work fine .

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore
import Firebase

class orderTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

 @IBOutlet var order: UITableView!

var db: Firestore!
var firstName = [String]()
var lastName = [String]()


 
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

    
    db = Firestore.firestore()



   let v = logInViewController()

   if  v.userNameField?.text == “Hi@example.com”  {
      
        loadData1()
          
    }
      
      if  v.userNameField?.text == “Hola@example.com”  {
        
           loadData2()
            
      }

}
     

  func loadData1() {
   
  db.collection(“Hi”).getDocuments()
        {
            (querySnapshot, err) in

            if let err = err
            {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
            }
            else
            {
                var count = 0
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    count += 1
                    print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())");
                    
                    self.firstName.append(document.get("firstname") as? String ?? "")
                    self.lastName.append(document.get("lastname") as? String ?? "")
           }

              
            }
            self.order.reloadData()
    }
   }

      
    



   func loadData2() {
   
     db.collection(“Hola”).getDocuments()
        {
            (querySnapshot, err) in

            if let err = err
            {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
            }
            else
            {
                var count = 0
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    count += 1
                    print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())");
                    
                    self.firstName.append(document.get("firstname") as? String ?? "")
                    self.lastName.append(document.get("lastname") as? String ?? "")
                 }

              
            }
            self.order.reloadData()
    }
   }
```

is there a simple way to achieve it ?

Comment: I don't know Swift but I know Firestore. rather than creating a collection per user why not creating a document per (which makes more sense) and make the id of the document is the username like for `helo@gmail.com` the document id should be `id`. then from you app you can get any data for that user using their email. if you are using Firebase auth, you can get the current user by https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#currentuser

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi because every user will get many document and i want to use collection per user

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase auth with the currentUser property.

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
let email = user.email
```

then use this email to grab their collection:

```
db.collection(email).getDocuments()
```

read more about this [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users)

Comment: what part of this didn't work? edit your question with the updated code